# Can I bulk store multiple pokemon from Sw/Sh to Pokemon Home at once

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-lets-go, pokemon-home

Can I select multiple pokemon to transfer to [Pokemon Home](https://home.pokemon.com/de-de/)?
Can I select whole boxes?
Can I select all pokemon from a game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I select multiple pokemon to transfer to Pokémon Home?
>
> Can I select whole boxes?

Yes, you can select multiple Pokémon and move entire boxes to Pokémon Home from Lets Go and Sword/Shield (and I’m assuming from Pokémon Bank as well).

Pokémon Home as the same multi-select feature that exists in Sword/Shield. While viewing your boxes to move between storage, press either LZ or RZ to change the selection options. To move whole boxes, just select every Pokémon in the box.

[image: multiselecting Pokemon]

> Can I select all pokemon from a game?

Pokémon Home supports all 8 generations. So yes, you can move any Pokémon from any supported game into Pokémon Home.

The only exception are Pokémon that are currently in your party. Since Lets Go storage functions differently and you see Pokémon in your party, it’ll prevent you from moving them

[image: unable to move Pokémon in party]